# Qt QTabWidget - auto set tab name number

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

I working on one application and I have problem with tab name.
When I click on push button (NEW) I want to dynamically create new tab.

With this function i create new file:

```
bool MainWindow::toolbarNewFile()
{

    QWidget *page = new QWidget;

    QTextEdit *codeEditor = new QTextEdit;

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

    layout->addWidget(codeEditor);

    page->setLayout(layout);

    tab_widget->addTab(page,"File");

    return true;
}
```

But all tabs have name "FILE"

How to set in tab name number. When i make new tab auto set number of the tab like this.

**File-1, File-2, File-3**

I try to set `counter i=0;` and in `addTab(page,"File-"+ i++);` Doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to covert integer to the `QString` to be able to concat it to the `QString`. Even better, you can use [QString::arg](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg) function and get readable and potentially faster code very easily:

```
tab_widget->addTab(page, QString("File-%1").arg(i++));
```

Where `i` is field in your class initialized to 1.

Comment: Or tab_widget->addTab(page,"File-"+QString::number(i++));

Comment: Original solution is generally faster, as you have `"File"` conversion to `QString`, `i` conversion to `QString` and unnecessary `QString::operator+` call, but in this case - it is valid way to do i, too.

Comment: @
Burgos Dot work all my new tabs have name "File-0". I                        int i = 0;
tab_widget->addTab(page, QString("File-%1").arg(i++));

Comment: @Makciook tab_widget->addTab(page,"File-"+QString::number(i++)); this return all file name have File-0, File-0, File-0

Comment: `int i` should be declared in the class, not in the function, as it will always have value of 0 if you enter the function.

Comment: @Ivan because you are always resetting i to 0.

Comment: I declare i in class and now have error :  only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class. I change int i = 0; to static const int i = 1; <-- C2105: '++' needs l-value

Comment: I fix this... Declare (int i;) in class in mainWindow::mainWindow set counter value. And now work fine... Ty guys ur great..